# Does apache commons fileupload support chunked uploads?

Tags: file-upload, apache-commons, http-chunked

We have moved to using PLupload for file uploads and found that it can support "chunked" file uploads.  The problem is that our server sees one large file upload as multiple smaller files coming in multiple POST requests.

Does anybody know if Apache Commons FileUpload supports chunked uploads?

Comment: What do you mean chunked?  do you mean HTTP chunking (which is a Servlet container matter) or do you mean a server-side upload progress API for file uploads with Apache Commons FileUpload ?

Comment: The servlet API does not provide a mechanism to break into HTTP chunking (since that defeats the point of the spec which is to process a HTTP Request to build and send a HTTP Response).  So HTTP chunking is working as intended in this regard.  More info on HTTP checking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding  it is nonsense to ask if Apache Commons FileUploads supports HTTP chunking since it is entirely a Servlet container (such as Tomcat and Jetty) matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW looking at the PLupload webpage the "Chunking" they are talking about is not "HTTP Chunking".  http://www.plupload.com/index.php

Their marketing term "Chunking" is their concept of sending a large payload up in small and separate HTTP requests.  The server is required to have logic to group, stitch up and verify all the small parts.  You are better off getting help on their forum on this.  There is no reason why this logic can not be created by you on the server side and maybe they have example Java code implementing it.

Useful info and pointer to their upload.php example (maybe you convert to Java and on top of Apache Commons FileUpload) :

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1484

What you are observing the small segments of a file arriving like they are separate files is exactly how the "PLupload Chunking" mechanism works.  This technique is not defined in any standard, but it is also not an uncommon solution to the problems it addresses.

The "HTTP Chunking" is standard for defining how to transfer a single HTTP Request (and/or HTTP Response) between click/server using a HTTP transfer encoding.  This is supported by all webservers and all browsers and has been around for a long time (since HTTP/1.1).

Comment: You are absolutely right.  From the perspective of Apache File upload one 8mb file with a chunk_size of 1mb looks like 8 files.  Each of those files has 3 params that help you tell where it came from.  chunk, chunks, and name (filename).  Use name to group files together, and chunk/chunks as in piece 2 (chunk) of 10 (chunks).